# App's background service seems to go to sleep

Tags: android, service

I have a `Service` instance that is listing for contact changes:

```
Application.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, mContactsObserver);
```

This is done on the `onStartCommand` and is unregistered on the `onDestroy`

That `Service` communicates with a Manager that lives on the `Application` instance.

---

With this setup in mind I have a strange bug:

1. I open the app everything works
2. I send the app to background and kill it, the service restarts and all works fine
3. But when I send the app to background sometimes the logs simply stop, the app seems to freeze... I don't receive any contact change notification, nor anything else, but the app isn't killed either. I have a `ScheduleThreadPool` that does not triggers its' tasks during this period either.

**Whenever I open the app again, all resumes as normal.** And the logs shows the the Service is not recreated it was still running.

Is this an expected behaviour due to some battery saving policy?

*Importante note: This is happening on a Samsung GT-I9515 with Android 4.4.2, so Doze is not the culprit.*